# Javascript - Unable to change object value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects.  Each object contains the name of a friend, their age, and their gender, like so:

```
var friends = [{name: "Dan",
            age: 34,
            gender: "male"},

            {name: "Chris",
            age: 30,
            gender: "male"},

            {name: "Laura",
            age: 32,
            gender: "female"}];
```

I have to write a function which can take any of the three friends and add one year to their age.  I've written this:

```
function hasBirthday(name){
    friends.forEach(function(person){
        if(name === person.name){
        person.age += 1;
        }
    }); return person.age;
}
```

Let's say I want to change Laura's age from 32 to 33.  I'd call the function thusly:

```
hasBirthday("Laura");
```

And if I were to assign the function to a variable and then console.log it, I would expect the output to be 33.  However, I always get the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: person is not defined.
```

Could anyone shed any light on why I keep getting this error message?  I'm completely stumped.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you adding a number to a persons name? Don't you want `person.age`?

Comment: well, i mean, `person` is in fact undefined at your return statement. (it's outside of the forEach)

Comment: If your goal was to return the new age, you'd have to store that value in a variable outside of the for each, then return the value of that variable after the for each. Or use a for loop and return inside.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. You've solved the problem.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you are returning person.age out of the scope of forEach loop. To solve the issue you can declare a variable that can have track of the age of the friend you are asking about. You can also change the age in the friends array as well by the index of the current element.

```
var friends = [{name: "Dan",
        age: 34,
        gender: "male"},

        {name: "Chris",
        age: 30,
        gender: "male"},

        {name: "Laura",
        age: 32,
        gender: "female"}]; 

function hasBirthday(name){
    var current_age = 0;
    friends.forEach(function(person, i){
        if(name === person.name){
            current_age = person.age + 1;
            friends[i].age = current_age; // you can update the global array as well.
        }
    });
    return current_age;
} 

hasBirthday("Laura");

console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just remove `return person.age;`

```
function hasBirthday(name){
    friends.forEach(function(person){
        if(name === person.name){
            person.age += 1;
        }
    });
    // return person.age;
}
hasBirthday("Laura"); //Laura has 33 now
```

If you need, also, the new age when do `hasBirthday("Laura")`, then modify like this.

```
function hasBirthday(name){
    var new_age = 0;
    friends.forEach(function(person){
        if(name === person.name){
            person.age += 1;
            new_age = person.age;
        }
    });
    return new_age;
}
alert(hasBirthday("Laura")); //Laura has 33 now
```

Think if you have two "Laura", funtion return only the last match. Also, when person don't exists, function return 0.

Answer (score -3):

you are not adding +1 to age. You have to compare the name and add +1 to that person's age

```js
function hasBirthday(name){
    friends.forEach(function(person){
        if(name === person.name){
        person.age += 1;
        }return person.age;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `return person.age` is still undefined